# I want to a number with specific length

Tags: javascript, numbers

I want to a number with specific length number

`Ex1 if num = '4.7' and length = 4 then output should be '4.7000',`

`Ex2 if num = '4' and length = 2 then output should be '4.00',`

**how can I convert this("4.00") string into 4.00 in JavaScript**

Comment: does `toFixed` not work for you?

Comment: Here is the documentation for [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) that Nina mentioned.

Comment: I am using String and toFixed  was not worked for me so I changed String to Int. Thanks!!

Comment: If your input is a string you need to convert it to a number before using toFixed: `valueAsString = parseFloat(valueAsString).toFixed(3)`

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed` is what you are looking for.

Have a go here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tofixed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate it as String you can use this script for that

```
function fixPadding(value, length) {  
    let split = (value+"").split('.');

    if (length === 0) {
        return split[0];
    }

    if (split.length > 1) {
        if (split[1].length > length) {
            return split[0]+'.'+split[1].substr(0, length);
        } else if (split[1].length < length) {
            return split[0]+'.'+split[1]+'0'.repeat(length-split[1].length);
        } else {
            return split[0]+'.'+split[1];
        }
    }

    return split[0]+'.'+'0'.repeat(length);
}
```

Otherwise, you should cast to int or float to use `toFixed` as the others recommended you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert your string into a float, and then [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to adjust the length.

```js
function convert(num, length) {
 return parseFloat(num).toFixed(length);
}
var num, length;

num = '4.7';
length = 4;
console.log( convert(num,length)); // prints 4.7000

num = '4';
length = 2;
console.log( convert(num,length)); // prints 4.00
```

Comment: please look what I asked

Comment: @vasudev.p Yes, i looked at what you asked. According to your question you want the string `'4.7'` to become `'4.7000'` if you give a length of 4, and the string `'4'` to be the string `'4.00'` if you give a length of 2. I just show you how to get `'4.7'` to become `'4.700'` if you use the length of 3. I assumed that you understood that you can change the 3 to 2 or 4, but I will update my answer to be extra clear.

Comment: @vasudev.p There you have it, exactly what you asked for with exactly the result that you gave in your examples.